# Insert Checkbox Array into Multiple MySQL table Columns with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I am pretty stumped, I thought this would work for sure. I want to insert multiple checkbox values (if selected) into different columns of one table.  I was attempting to do this with a for loop and keeping the naming convention consistent so I could utilize the for loop with the checkbox array. Here is php code:

```
$connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","","employee_db");
if(isset($_POST['check'])){
    $check = $_POST['check'];
    if($check){
        print_r($check);
    }else{
        echo "nothing checked";
    }

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($check);$i++){
        $query = "INSERT INTO  `checklist_test` (`$check[$i]`) VALUE (`\"$check[$i]\"`)"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        if(!$result){
            die("NOPE <br>" . mysqli_error($connection));
        }else{
            echo "yup";
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the HTML

```
<form action="" method="post>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="check1">Check1
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="check2">Check2
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="check3">Check3
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

The MySQL Columns are "id, check1, check2, check3" so SQL should look like:

```
INSERT INTO `checklist_test` (`id`, `check1`, `check2`, `check3`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'test', 'test', 'test');
```

Appreciater outside P.O.V. that I need thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you the execute the query inside the loop, you would be executing x number of queries (or inserting x number of rows) rather than inserting into x number of columns.  There is really no need to use a loop here since you have a set number of columns.

Use echo statements to print out the queries to see what you are running and you'll see why this isn't working.

You also should never put user input directly into a MySQL query.  Read up on SQL injections.